# Angular Changing/Replacing the value in a string based on the User selection

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dynamic-data

I am working on an offer letter template that will replace/modify Dynamic Data Points like Name, Address, Role, Salary, etc based on the candidate selected from a list of candidates. There is a fixed syntax for a dynamic data points i.e they will be enclosed within `<<>>`, for example :

```
Welcome to the family, <<Name>> 
You will be paid <<Salary>> for the duration of your employment.
```

In other words, these few data points will change by selecting the candidate we want to offer the job and the rest of the template will remain the same. Here is a [demo to help you understand](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slsu2f).

**This is a dummy array I have created with 1 template, In the real-world app, I can have many templates with different clauseNames, so I am looking for a permanent fix.**
.ts file, Template List :

```
[{

    templateId: 1,
    templateName: "Offer",
    clauses: [
      {
        clauseName: "Introduction",
        clauseId: 1,
        texts: [
          {
            text: "Hello <<Name>>, Welcome to the Machine",
            textId: 1,
          }]
      },
      {
        clauseName: "Address",
        clauseId: 2,
        texts: [
          {
            text: "<<Address>>",
            textId: 2,
          }]
      },
      {
        clauseName: "Date Of Joining",
        clauseId: 3,
        texts: [
          {
            text: "You can join us on <<DateOfJoining>>",
            textId: 3,
          }]
      },
    ]
  }]
```

and here is the candidate list,

```
  candidateList = [
    { name: "Simba", address: "Some Random Cave" },
    { name: "Doe John", address: "line 4, binary avenue, Mobo" },
    { name: "B Rabbit", address: "8 mile road, Detroit" },
    { name: "Peter Griffin", address: "Spooner Street" },
    { name: "Speedy Gonzales", address: "401, hole 34, Slyvester Cat Road" },
    { name: "Morty", address: "Time Machine XYZ" },
    { name: "Brock", address: "pokeball 420, Medic center" },
  ]
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer. You can move the replace logic to another function. But I hope you'll get the idea. Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to replace those placeholders such as:

```
var result = text.text.replace(/\<\<(.*?)\>\>/g, function(match, token) {
       return candidate[token.toLowerCase()];
    });
```

One way to incorporate this to your display is by creating a property that returns the formatted text.

I have updated your [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q1tfbe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Thanks dude, this is working perfectly fine. I will check it for some other strings tho. Anyways, you just made my Saturday a little easier.

Comment: @MenimE You are welcome. Just a note - you can add new placeholders such as <<birthday>> or <<username>> without modifying anything in the replace logic since Regex will handle that.. you just need to match these with the object properties such as candidate.birthday and candidate.username

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16vse3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I have modified the logic in below method:

```
  showTeplate(name,address,doj) {
    this.clauseList = [];
    for (let a of this.templateList) {
      if (a.clauses != null) {
        for (let cl of a.clauses) {
          const tempObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cl));
          tempObj.texts.forEach(textObj => {
            textObj.text = textObj.text.replace("<<Name>>",name);
            textObj.text = textObj.text.replace("<<Address>>",address);
            textObj.text = textObj.text.replace("<<DateOfJoining>>",doj);
          })
          this.clauseList.push(tempObj)

        }
      }
    }
    console.log("Clause list", this.clauseList)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, man! But will it be feasible if there are multiple, let's say 17 to 18 clauses that we need to add in the offer letter?

Comment: will you take a look at it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-77ccva I have described the issue in the .ts file